# Error when installing quantmod in r

Tags: r, package

I am Trying to install "quantmod" in R but I can't manage. I tried unistalling and installing R again, and updating to the lastest version. I use windows. I get the following errors:

```
> library(quantmod)
Loading required package: TTR
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TTR’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: curl, curl_download, curl_echo, curl_escape, curl_fetch_disk, curl_fetch_memory, curl_fetch_multi, curl_fetch_stream, curl_options, curl_unescape, curl_version, form_data, form_file, handle_cookies, handle_data, handle_reset, handle_setform, handle_setheaders, handle_setopt, has_internet, ie_get_proxy_for_url, ie_proxy_info, multi_add, multi_cancel, multi_list, multi_run, multi_set, new_handle, new_pool, nslookup, parse_date, parse_headers
Error: package ‘TTR’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘print.curl_handle’, ‘print.curl_multi’, ‘print.form_data’, ‘print.form_file’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

When trying to install TTR:

```
> library(TTR)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TTR’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: curl, curl_download, curl_echo, curl_escape, curl_fetch_disk, curl_fetch_memory, curl_fetch_multi, curl_fetch_stream, curl_options, curl_unescape, curl_version, form_data, form_file, handle_cookies, handle_data, handle_reset, handle_setform, handle_setheaders, handle_setopt, has_internet, ie_get_proxy_for_url, ie_proxy_info, multi_add, multi_cancel, multi_list, multi_run, multi_set, new_handle, new_pool, nslookup, parse_date, parse_headers
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘print.curl_handle’, ‘print.curl_multi’, ‘print.form_data’, ‘print.form_file’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

PF: I get a similar error when trying to execute the "forecast" package

```
> library(forecast)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: curl, curl_download, curl_echo, curl_escape, curl_fetch_disk, curl_fetch_memory, curl_fetch_multi, curl_fetch_stream, curl_options, curl_unescape, curl_version, form_data, form_file, handle_cookies, handle_data, handle_reset, handle_setform, handle_setheaders, handle_setopt, has_internet, ie_get_proxy_for_url, ie_proxy_info, multi_add, multi_cancel, multi_list, multi_run, multi_set, new_handle, new_pool, nslookup, parse_date, parse_headers
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘print.curl_handle’, ‘print.curl_multi’, ‘print.form_data’, ‘print.form_file’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is, but to install a package you use `install.packages()`. I assume you are trying to load a package. Try installing package `TTR` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried that already but I get similar error message.

Answer (score 1):

Linux terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

R console:

```
install.packages("quantmod")
```